# Debian 10 and MongoDB

Tags: debian, mysql, mongodb

Has anyone successfully installed Mongo on Debian 10? I am new to working on Debian. I'm getting these messages when I try to install. I tried MySQL too and got similar messages. Are these databases not ready for Debian buster?

```
E: The repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.0 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster In
```

Comment: See also https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=916107 why mongodb is not included in Debian Buster.

Comment: See also https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-37768 to track when it will be available.

Answer (score 0):

As per the MongoDB [website](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/):

> MongoDB only provides packages for 64-bit builds of Debian 8 and 9. See Supported Platforms for more information.